# Python: ConfigParser.NoSectionError: No section: 'TestInformation'

Tags: python, configparser

I am getting ConfigParser.NoSectionError: No section: 'TestInformation' error using the above code.

```
def LoadTestInformation(self):        
    config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()    
    print(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'App.cfg'))

    with open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'App.cfg'),'r') as configfile:       
        config.read(configfile)
        return config.items('TestInformation')
```

The file path is correct, I have double checked. and the config file has TestInformation section

```
[TestInformation]

IEPath = 'C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe'

URL = 'www.google.com.au'

'''date format should be '<Day> <Full Month> <Full Year>'

SystemDate = '30 April 2013'
```

in a app.cfg file. Not sure what I am doing wrong

Comment: `app.cfg` or `App.cfg`?

Comment: App.cfg. should I use only app.cfg?

Comment: In your question's last line you say you have put all this in `app.cfg` but in your code you are opening `App.cfg`. I'll take that as a typo.

Comment: Try using `readfp()` instead of `read`. `read()` expects a list of filenames, `readfp()` expects a file object

Comment: I'll post it as an answer (for Reps :D)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `readfp()` function rather than `read()` since you are opening the file before reading it. See [Official Documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html#ConfigParser.RawConfigParser.read).

```
def LoadTestInformation(self):        
    config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()    
    print(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'App.cfg'))

    with open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'App.cfg'),'r') as configfile:       
        config.readfp(configfile)
        return config.items('TestInformation')
```

You can continue to use `read()` if you skip the file opening step and instead the full path of the file to the `read()` function

```
def LoadTestInformation(self):        
    config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()    
    my_file = (os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'App.cfg'))
    config.read(my_file)
    return config.items('TestInformation')
```