# Python configparser.NoSectionError: No section: 'data'

Tags: python, configparser

I'm getting **configparser.NoSectionError: No section: 'data'** error. I've also found some relevant questions in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35016479/python-configparser-nosectionerror-no-section) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16601757/python-configparser-nosectionerror-no-section-testinformation) links, but neither of them worked for me. I've also checked the file path and it's correct.

Below is my main.py code:

```
import torch
import argparse
from utils.configparser_hook import get_config
from utils.global_variables import Global
from utils.initializer import initialize
from utils.runner import run

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    required_args = ["config"]
    normal_args = ["gpu"]
    for arg in required_args + normal_args:
        parser.add_argument("--{}".format(arg), required=arg in required_args)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    
    device = torch.device("cuda:{}".format(args.gpu) if args.gpu and torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
    Global.device = device
    print("Device:", device)

    config = get_config(args.config)
    config.add_section("runtime")

    parameters = initialize(config, device)

    run(parameters, config, device)
```

The content of config file is as follow:

```
[train]
epoch = 15
batch_size = 200
shuffle = True
valid_interval = 1
save_strategy = save_best

[test]
batch_size = 200
shuffle = False

[data]
reader_name = MavenReader
formatter_name = BilstmFormatter
word2vec_file = 100.utf8
split_labels = True

[model]
model_name = Bilstm
num_layers = 1
hidden_size = 256
dropout = 0.5

[optimizer]
optimizer_name = Adam
lr = 1e-3
weight_decay = 1e-8
```

Also, the ConfigParserHook class is as follow in which it parses the input config file:

```
import functools
import configparser

class ConfigParserHook(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.config = configparser.RawConfigParser()

    def read(self, config_file):
        self.config.read(config_file, encoding="utf-8")

def set_hook(func_name):
    @functools.wraps(getattr(configparser.RawConfigParser, func_name))
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return getattr(self.config, func_name)(*args, **kwargs)
    
    return wrapper

def get_config(config_file):
    for func_name in dir(configparser.RawConfigParser):
        if not func_name.startswith("_") and func_name != "read":
            setattr(ConfigParserHook, func_name, set_hook(func_name))
    setattr(ConfigParserHook, "__getitem__", set_hook("__getitem__"))
    
    config = ConfigParserHook()
    config.read(config_file)

    return config
```

I'm running the script following the `python main.py --config [path of config files]` command line and got the below error:

```
  File "main.py", line 23, in <module>
    parameters = initialize(config, device)
  File "C:\Users\S3763411\Desktop\MAVEN-dataset-main\MAVEN-dataset-main\baselines\DMCNN_BiLSTM_(CRF)\utils\initializer.py", line 12, in initialize
    reader = get_class("reader", config.get("data", "reader_name"))(config)
  File "C:\Users\S3763411\Desktop\MAVEN-dataset-main\MAVEN-dataset-main\baselines\DMCNN_BiLSTM_(CRF)\utils\configparser_hook.py", line 14, in wrapper
    return getattr(self.config, func_name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\allennlp\lib\configparser.py", line 780, in get
    d = self._unify_values(section, vars)
  File "E:\allennlp\lib\configparser.py", line 1146, in _unify_values
    raise NoSectionError(section) from None
configparser.NoSectionError: No section: 'data'
```

I don't really understand why it raises this error while I'm defining the correct file path. Not quite sure what I'm doing wrong to get this error.
Thanks for your time and help in advance.

Comment: "I don't really understand why it raises this error while I'm defining the correct file path." Well, the error message comes from the config parser, and it says something that seems to be describing a problem with the config file. Did you try looking at the *contents of* the config file, to make sure it contains everything that the documentation says it should?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Thanks for the reply. Yes, I've checked the config file which consists of a set of on input parameters. I've also added the content file in my question to have a better idea of the content.

Comment: I'm debugging the same error, perhaps this answer is related to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35017127/7437143